# Multiply Matrix in Assembly with using mul/imul/shifting

Tags: assembly, x86, matrix-multiplication

What is the way to multiply matrix at herself without using mul/imul/shifting instructions in Assembly?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you please further elaborate on what are you attempting to do and why? Why should the solution not use the aforementioned instructions? There is a big gap between the concept of matrix and assembly as there is no standard matrix representation in x86 assembly. In the end, you need to translate the algorithm (matrix multiplication) into operations that can be expressed in assembly (calculate address of cells to multiply, retrieve their values, multiply them, store them in the result matrix). Could you rephrase this question in such operations?

Comment: You can use `add eax,eax` as a left-shift by 1.  That would let you implement a multiply function using the usual bit-test O(log2(n)) algorithm with shifts / adds, but without using an shift mnemonics.  Otherwise you can always implement multiply by repeated addition, which is horribly slow.

Comment: Looping over a matrix doesn't require multiplication in the first place, so the only thing you'd have to change vs. a normal (non SIMD) integer implementation is the actual multiplication  (and you can use it for bounds calculation, too, if needed).  Or you could convert integers to FP and use `mulsd` to get fast hardware multiply without using the `mul` or `imul` instructions!  Or even use SIMD integer `pmulld` if you have SSE4.1.